# Deleting the last line of a file in Haskell

Tags: haskell, io, bytestring

I am a beginner to Haskell and am trying to rewrite one of my shell scripts in Haskell as a test. One of the things I am trying to accomplish is removing the last line of a file and reading its value.

I tried to use `readFile` and then `writeFile`, but I can't because it is lazy.
I was able to get it to work using this code:

```
import           Data.List
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8         as B
import qualified Data.Text                     as T
import qualified Data.Text.Encoding            as TL

erase filename = do
  contents <- B.readFile filename
  let array = map (T.unpack . TL.decodeUtf8) (B.lines contents)
  B.writeFile filename $ B.pack (intercalate "\n" (init array))
  print $ last array
```

This turns the lines of the file into a list and then writes to the file without the last line. It is using the ByteString so it won't be lazy. However, I think that this way is very verbose and does it weirdly. Is there some function that deletes a line from a file or how can this code be improved?

Comment: You are rewriting the editor that does the deletion more than you are rewriting the script that invokes the editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise *not* to write to the same file: *most* linux commands will normally always write to a different file, and optionally then move the target file over the original file. For example if you sort, you always have at least *or* the original file, *or* the result file.

We can implement a helper function to obtain the content of the first lines and the last line:

```
safeUnsnoc :: a -> [a] -> ([a], a)
safeUnsnoc d = go
  where go [] = ([], d)
        go [x] = ([], x)
        go (x:xs) = (x:a, b) where ~(a, b) = go xs
```

This is often better: it will avoid enumerating two times over the list, so this can be more memory conservative.

Then we thus can read from the file, store the file in a temporary file, and do the file move:

```
import System.Directory(renameFile)
import System.IO.Temp(writeSystemTempFile)

erase filename = do
  (content, lastLine) <- safeUnsnoc "" . lines <$> readFile filename
  tmp <- writeSystemTempFile "temp-init" (unlines content)
  renameFile tmp filename
  putStrLn lastLine
```